# How to get User Object after Request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I tried to implement the Example given by Alamofire: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#generic-response-object-serialization

The Problem is i want to get the User Object for my completion handler, after the Request:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://example.com/users/mattt")
         .responseObject { (response: Response<User, NSError>) in
             debugPrint(response)
         }
```

Does anybody know how to access the User Object from the response ?

Comment: You need to parse the JSON after your request to get the data and place it in array or whatever, the response where you find your returned JSON ! you should update the question with incoming data (response) so we can help you!

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but i think it is already parsed with the custom ResponseObjectSerializable. And the "
    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) {
        self.username = response.URL!.lastPathComponent!
        self.name = representation.valueForKeyPath("name") as! String
    }
}" is also fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your `User` object using `response.result.value!` Like :

```
   Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://example.com/users/mattt")
     .responseObject { (response: Response<User, NSError>) in
         debugPrint(response)
        print(response.result.value!.username) //It will print username if `username` key belongs to your User object.
     }
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Accept my answer if it helped! Tick mark on left side